# Expo react native android is uploading 'contact list'. App removed from google play

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play, android-permissions

Recently my expo managed react native android app was removed from google play store.

They claimed that my app was uploading users 'CONTACT LIST'.

Actually i never used contact list in the app.

**Here is the email from google play:**

> App Status: Removed Your app has been removed due to the policy
> issue(s) listed below. This app won't be available to users until you
> submit a compliant update.
>
> Issue found: APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE​ Your app is not
> compliant with the User Data policy.
>
> Your app is uploading users' CONTACT LIST information without a
> prominent disclosure.
>
> As per Google Play’s User Data policy, in cases where your app’s
> access, collection, use, or sharing of personal and sensitive user
> data may not be within the reasonable expectation of the user of the
> product or feature in question, you must provide an in-app disclosure
> of your data access, collection, use, and sharing and seek affirmative
> user consent.
>
> Your use case requires a Prominent Disclosure in accordance with this
> policy.
>
> The in-app Prominent Disclosure: Must comprehensively disclose how
> your app collects, uses and shares user data. To meet policy
> requirements, it’s recommended that you reference the following
> example language format for Prominent Disclosure when it’s required:
> “[This app] collects/transmits/syncs/stores [type of data] to enable
> [”feature”], [in what scenario].” Must be within the app itself,
> displayed in the normal usage of the app and not require the user to
> navigate into a menu or settings. Cannot only be placed in a privacy
> policy or terms of service. Cannot be included with other disclosures
> unrelated to personal and sensitive user data collection. Requests for
> user consent: Must be clear and unambiguous. Must require affirmative
> user action (for example, tap to accept, tick a check-box). Must not
> interpret navigation away from the disclosure (including tapping away
> or pressing the back or home button) as consent. Must not use
> auto-dismissing or expiring messages as a means of obtaining user
> consent. Must be granted by the user before your app can begin to
> collect or access the personal and sensitive user data. Issue details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> Version code 13 About the User Data policy You must be transparent in
> how you handle user data (for example, information collected from or
> about a user, including device information). That means disclosing the
> access, collection, use, handling, and sharing of user data from your
> app, and limiting the use of the data to the policy compliant purposes
> disclosed.
>
> Issue found: APP HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ IN PLAY DEVELOPER CONSOLE BUT
> IT IS NOT ADEQUATE Your app is not compliant with the User Data
> policy. Specifically,
>
> Your app is uploading users' CONTACT LIST information without posting
> an adequate privacy policy in the designated field in Play Developer
> Console. Privacy Policy in the designated field in Play Developer
> Console does not disclose the collection of CONTACT LIST. Privacy
> Policy in the designated field in Play Developer Console does not
> disclose the usage of collected CONTACT LIST. Issue details
>
> We found an issue in the following area(s):
>
> Version code 13 About the User Data policy You must be transparent in
> how you handle user data (for example, information collected from or
> about a user, including device information). That means disclosing the
> access, collection, use, handling, and sharing of user data from your
> app, and limiting the use of the data to the policy compliant purposes
> disclosed. Action required: Submit an updated app for review Here's
> what to do to help get your app on Google Play: Make sure to read the
> applicable policies or requirements listed below: User Data policy
> Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to
> address the issue described above. You may also want to check your
> app's store listing for compliance, if applicable. Address the issue
> mentioned above, deactivate the non-compliant version and upload a
> compliant version with an incremented version code. In addition to
> your Production release, if you have other release types that you use
> for testing and/or quality assurance checks (for example, Internal
> test, Closed, Open), please make required changes and update those
> tracks as well. Make sure that the non-compliant version is under the
> “Not included” section of the release. Double check that your app is
> compliant with all other Developer Program Policies. If you made
> changes to your app bundle, store listing, or APK, please sign in to
> your Play Console and submit the update(s)

**Here is my package.json file content**

```
  "name": "myabcapp",
  "version": "1.23.4",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view": "^2.0.4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.4.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.23.3",
    "apisauce": "^2.1.6",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~6.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~3.0.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.41",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.14",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.2.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^10.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.2.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3"
  },
  "private": true
```

**Here is my app.json file content**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My abc App",
    "slug": "myabcapp",
    "version": "1.23.4",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          },
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "30.0.2",
            "kotlinVersion": "1.7.10"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      "./react-native-maps-plugin",
      [
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
        {
          "merchantIdentifier": "",
          "enableGooglePay": false
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "appleTeamId": "M34O29V5ZF",
          "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "mode": "production"
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-tracking-transparency",
        {
          "userTrackingPermission": "My Abc App wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads."
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin",
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "471576785566340",
          "clientToken": "7c51e110a70788y5418478cebdcbcf7d",
          "displayName": "My Abc App",
          "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false,
          "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
          "isAutoInitEnabled": true
        }
      ],
      "expo-localization"
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "backgroundColor": "#f85c70",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/icon96x96.png",
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true,
      "androidMode": "default"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "bitcode": "Debug",
      "usesAppleSignIn": true,
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.myabcapp",
      "buildNumber": "30",
      "usesIcloudStorage": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "My Abc App wants to track you to collect IDFA to deliver personalised ads.",
        "NSCameraUsageDescription": "My Abc App uses the camera to capture and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "My Abc App needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "My Abc App needs access to the photo library to select and upload user profile image and Listing Image to the server.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "My Abc App usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "My Abc App usages device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "My Abc App uses device location on listing information, Listing search Data and User information.",
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "My Abc App uses your microphone while taking video of your product for uploading in listing information.",
        "CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations": true,
        "UIBackgroundModes": ["remote-notification"],
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "cstr6suwn8.skadnetwork"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "v9wttpbfk4.skadnetwork"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "n38lu8286g.skadnetwork"
          }
        ]
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "AIzaSyBpEfX_PyYbLxGa07zjvLJbZefx",
        "usesNonExemptEncryption": false
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myabcapp",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyBpEfX_PyYbLxGa07zjvLJbZefx"
        }
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#fff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "CAMERA",
        "CAMERA_ROLL",
        "MEDIA_LIBRARY",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "READ_PHONE_STATE",
        "READ_CONTACTS",
        "LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
        "com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID",
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
      ],
      "versionCode": 31
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "scheme": "myabcapp",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "47c5dce0-69e9-4ebf-a637-89k9879j67j8"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-789768768767698~899798798",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-987989879879~9879879798"
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me please? I want to upload a new version of the app that does not has this issue. Also can anybody tell me that what is actually using the contact list?

Addition :

I can see "READ_CONTACTS" permission in app.json file. Can anybody tell me which of my current packages is requesting this permission?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- you need to add a prominent disclosure to your app. This disclosure should inform the user that the app is accessing their contact list and should provide an option for the user to grant or deny permission for the app to access their contact list.
- install the expo-contacts package to access the user's contact list.

  ```
  expo install expo-contacts
  ```
- request permission from the user to access their contact list.

  ```
  import * as Contacts from 'expo-contacts';

  async function requestContactPermission() {
   const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
   if (status === 'granted') {
    console.log('Contact permission granted');
   } else {
    console.log('Contact permission denied');
   }
  }
  ```
- you need to add a prominent disclosure to your app. You can do this by displaying a modal to the user when the app is launched. The modal should inform the user that the app is accessing their contact list and should provide an option for the user to grant or deny permission.
- create a privacy policy for your app using a privacy policy generator & publish on your website. then goto app-content & provide url & send an update of your app to the google Play Store.

Comment: Actually i do not intend to read or upload any contact. I want to remove this contact uploading thing. There is no relation between my app and user contact. I want to get rid of contact uploading. Please help.